# How to wait for Object Listener to finish handling Event?

Tags: android

In `onCreate()` I use a `setOnItemSelectedListener()` to a spinner. Then in `onResume()` I call `setSelection()` on that same spinner. What happens is the Listener gets called but the events are not in the order I expected to happen. If my code looks like this:

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(...
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(){...

        Log.e("marker", "stage 2");
    ...}
...});
```

and

```
Log.e("marker", "stage 1");
sp1.setSelection(1, true);
Log.e("marker", "stage 3");
```

In LogCat the events happen in this order: stage1, stage3, then stage 2. Obviously, I'd want it to be stage1, stage2, then stage3. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Why is this important? If you really need this then you can remove the listener before calling setSelection() and call onItemSelected() directly after that (this is an ugly but simple solution)

Comment: It has to do with dependent spinners (I actually have 5 of them) and how to recreate their states (what items are selected) after the containing activity is destroyed. So it goes like this, sp2 is dependent on sp1, sp3 is dependent on sp2, and so on. I'm getting an indexOutOfBoundsExeception because when I call sp2.setSelection(), sp2's adapter has not been updated yet (is is supposed to be handled in sp1's onItemSelected).

Comment: Hey, @MichaelButscher. Would you mind writing that as an answer (So I can site it as the correct answer/sol'n). I solved it by myself and my code ended up like what you said. It looked horrible, too many if-else statements mainly because of the dependencies.
Can I ask a related question here? Is there a standard way to implement dependent spinners without having to use so many if-else statements? I think this is a fairly common situation. Like when a user needs to input his/her address. You would have a STATE-spinner, CITY/TOWN-spinner, and STREET-Spinner which will be populated accordingly.

Comment: I have posted it as answer. Why do you not create an OnItemSelectedListener per spinner in which you fill the next spinner with the right data, e.g. when STATE was selected fill the CITY/TOWN spinner? I don't understand yet why you need this particular order of calls. About the if/elses: you can create an external data file (an asset) and read and parse it on application startup. For more details you should ask a separate question

Comment: One `setOnItemSelectedListener` is exactly what I do. I need the calls to be in that particular order because if not I'll get `indexOutOfBoundsExeception`s.

Comment: This sounds like a different underlying problem to me. You should post the relevant code and logcat output in a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this then you can remove the listener before calling `setSelection()` and call `onItemSelected()` directly after that (this is an ugly but simple solution)